# How to calculate total count of previous year

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have student data classified as per the year of enrollment and semester. For calculating retention rate, I need to divide all retained students for CY by total count of PY. How should I create a formula for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Please do include some sample input data (as per your data structure) and desired  output in respect of that sample data, so that you can be helped.  Without data structure, it is very hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look something like this

```
Calc 1
IF Year = 2021 THEN Amount END

Calc 2
IF Year = 2020 THEN Amount END
```

Then you do `Calc 1 - Calc 2` in another calculated field. Or you can also use lookup function if it is a table calculation

[Lookup Function -1](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm)

Comment: These calculations won't work because where Year will be 2021, the value of year 2020 will be null and therefore further calculations won't work

Comment: If he has the whole data in the view, the sum should work